# Property 'filter' does not exist

Tags: angular, rxjs

I would like to get  user and filter whether the given username exists. I have problem with  property

> 'filter' does not exist on type 'Object'

```
    TakeUsernameIfExist(user: User) {
    return this.http.get(this.rootUrl + 'api/TakeUserName/' + user.UserName )
      .delay(1000)
      .map(users => users.filter( data => data === user.UserName))
      .map(users => !users.length);
}
```

I added import for filter and the problem is still.

> import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
>   My Web API method:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/TakeUserName/{username}")]
    public  string TakeUserName(string username)
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        var result =  userStore.FindByNameAsync(username);
        if(result==null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return result.Result.UserName;
        }

    }
```

Any help or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `users` is an object. `filter` only works in `array`. see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: How to filter request get without property  **filter** because I don't have array.

Comment: Show us the value of `users`

Comment: @kamilD what is in your response from that URL?

Comment: What is the value of `users`?

Comment: @Zlatko if username exist response return this value otherwise it will return null

Comment: Which value? It seems like you're returning a single user, not an array of users. Just copy-paste here what you get in that bckend response (take it from the network tab in the dev console).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you're NOT returning a LIST (or Array ) from you WEBAPI BUT you're return an OBJECT.. and Filter JS method works on ARRAY

so here you don't need the filter method cause you're searching for username (and you can't have more than one user in Identity Asp.NET with 2 similar username )

so try this in your WEB API return a bool:

```
   [HttpGet]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("api/TakeUserName/{username}")]
    public async<IHttpActionResult> TakeUserName(string username) //<-- IHttpActionResult  is better
    {
        var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new ApplicationDbContext());
        var manager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);

        var result =await userStore.FindByNameAsync(username);


            return  (result==null || !result.IsSuccess //<-- not sure for this prorperty name) ? Ok(false) : Ok( !string.isNullOrEmtpy(result.UserName);


    }
```

so in your client:

```
TakeUsernameIfExist(user: User) : Promise<bool> {
    return this.http.get<bool>(this.rootUrl + 'api/TakeUserName/' + user.UserName ).toPromise()

}
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I pass the existing userName request return true, but when I give a non-existent userName It will throws error: System.NullReferenceException' in visual studio.

Comment: `IsSuccess` not exist. There is property `IsCompleted` but all time return me false. `return (result == null || !result.IsCompleted)  ? Ok(false) : Ok( !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Result.UserName));`

Comment: no ... not isCompleted ... be sure to put await in front of  userStore.FindByNameAsync(username);

Comment: Happy it helped you!!..if it works rate it if you want .. thnx!

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't rate it because my reputation is under 15.